# Aar in repository. External dependency and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: repository, gradle, android-studio

I want to use JazzyListView in my Project. in Android studio. 
If I import library like a module all is fine.

```
compile project(':library')
```

but I have problem when library(aar) stored in local maven repository.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.twotoasters:jazzylistview:1.0.+'
}
```

In runtime activity started and show me a grid/list, but when I scroll it(when animation started)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator throwed

This library has a dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

used:
http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds

Comment: what is your pom file for `com.twotoasters:jazzylistview`?

Comment: As from url reference it will not generate correct pom file with `mvn install:install-file`. So your aar file in your local repository doesn't have correct dependencies

Comment: how to properly place an aar file in the local repository?
jazzylistview have pom file: https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView/blob/master/library/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `maven` installed then do next:

1. Clone https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView.git
2. Step into folder JazzyListView/library and run `mvn clean install`

After `maven` will try to build library from scratch and deploy it to your local repository with correct pom file